# animated javascript scrollLeft using XUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, tween, xui

i want to animate my scrollLeft = value using XUI (note that I can't use any JQuery animation for this one). I tried using the tween function as such: x$('#divID')tween(scrollLeft : value + 'px') and it didn't solve the problem.

Do any of you have an idea on how I can get an animated scrollLeft using XUI? I would really appreciate it. Thank you and God Bless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate scrollLeft as it is a DOM property, you can only animate CSS styles with XUI.

See [documentation](http://xuijs.com/docs/fx) for reference.